# Finding an unequal determinant of a squared matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. Find squared matrixes $A_{ij}$
with $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\A_{21} & A_{22}\\\end{bmatrix}\biggl) \neq det(A_{11})\cdot det(A_{22}) - det(A_{12})\cdot det(A_{21}).$

**My idea:**
I thought about inserting random numbers into a squared matrix but how do I know if $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\A_{21} & A_{22}\\\end{bmatrix}\biggl) \neq det(A_{11})\cdot det(A_{22}) - det(A_{12})\cdot det(A_{21}).$ actually applies?

Let's say that I have the following matrix: $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1\\2 & 3\\\end{bmatrix}\biggl) = 4\cdot3-1\cdot2=10.$

Do I get any valuable informations by doing this or what route should I take instead? I don't see how this: $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\A_{21} & A_{22}\\\end{bmatrix}\biggl) \neq det(A_{11})\cdot det(A_{22}) - det(A_{12})\cdot det(A_{21})$ is even possible at all.

Any hints guding me to the right direction I much appreciate.

Comment: Does someone know a better way to title the question? That was literally the only title I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{11}=A_{22}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &1  \\1  &1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{12}=A_{12}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &1  \\1  &2 \\
\end{bmatrix} .
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &1 &1&1 \\1  &1 &1&2\\1  &1 &1&1 \\1  &2 &1&1\\
\end{bmatrix} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Now calculate the determinants.

Comment: The determinant of the matrix $A$ is 0. But how does this proof the initial problem? I don't really understand that.

Comment: $det(A_{12})\cdot det(A_{21})$ is non-zero, but the other terms are zero, so the formula is shown.

Comment: Thanks, I have one last question though. In your answer you have written that $A_{12} =A_{12}$ but since you established that $A_{11} = A_{22}$ shouldn't the second one be $A_{12} = A_{21}$ or what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Typo ? ... missed an equals sign  ? corrected now.